# Table mislabeled as figure

Tags: tables, hyperref, captions, ref, autoref

I have an image and a table and they need to appear in the same page. The way I'm doing that right now is by wrapping them both in a figure. The problem I'm having is I'm trying to reference the table and LaTex keeps on labeling it as a figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

stuff stuff \autoref{table:nmr_nitro} blah blah.

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{3-nitrobenzonitrile.png}
\captionof{figure}{3-Nitrobenzonitrile with hydrogens assignments}
\label{figure:nmr_fig_nitro}

\begin{threeparttable}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\captionof{table}{NMR of 3-nitrobenzonitrile}
\label{table:nmr_nitro}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
\textbf{Some Data} & \textbf{Assignment} \\
\midrule
8.542; 2.0 (2H); m;        & A, B \\
7.960; 2.1 (2H); m;        & C, D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I found two solutions-ish to this problem. The first is to use manual instead of autoref and just manually label all my links. The other is to put `\captionsetup{type=table}` above my table caption but this seems like a hack. Is there any builtin, smooth way to do this?

Comment: `\captionsetup{type=table}` is not a hack. This is a proper solution. Using `\captionof` (which uses `\captionsetup{type*=table}` internally) is a hack which does not set a hyperref anchor etc. For this reason `table:nmr_nitro` points to the start of the `figure` when using `\captionof{table}{...}`, at least from hyperrefs point of view.

Comment: ...however it would be nice if using `\captionof` would not lead to a wrong labeled float type, so I will take a look at it. See also: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/53

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: `\captionsetup{type=table}` placed before the `threeparttable` is the correct way to go. Don't use `\captionof`, use `\caption` instead.

Long explanation:

How does `\autoref` work internally? It takes the 1st part of the hyper anchor name to determine the type, afterwards it uses the type to display the name of the type plus the usual reference one would get with `\ref`, too.

This works perfectly when dealing with sections etc.: `\section` generates a hyper anchor name starting with `section.` and places an anchor of this name in the document, so `\autoref` will display something like `Section 1`, and when clicking on it, it will jump to the hyper anchor `section.1` which was placed at the `\section` command.

But when dealing with floating environments like `figure` and `table`, the situation becomes bad. `\caption` is the command which increases the counter here, and therefore the hyper anchor will be generated here. What is bad about it? Since the hyper anchor is placed at `\caption`, clicking on a link will jump to the caption and not to the start of the floating environment. Especially if the caption is below the figure content this is not a satisfying user experience.

Because of this the former maintainer of `hyperref` (Heiko Oberdiek) invented the `hypcap` package. It offers a command called `\capstart` which will do the hyper anchor stuff and uses `\@captype` (= the name of the floating environment) as type. Usually this works fine. But when combining with a command like `\captionof` we get a problem: The hyper anchor name (including the type) was already set by `\capstart`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap,capt-of}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

stuff stuff \autoref{table:nmr_nitro} blah blah.

\begin{figure}

\capstart % Start of table
\begin{threeparttable}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\captionof{table}{NMR of 3-nitrobenzonitrile}
\label{table:nmr_nitro}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
\textbf{Some Data} & \textbf{Assignment} \\
\midrule
8.542; 2.0 (2H); m;        & A, B \\
7.960; 2.1 (2H); m;        & C, D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This document (which does not use the `caption` package) leads to the same false result as your document. What to do about it? Since `\capstart` has no argument and uses `\@captype` as type, we could offer something like `\capstartof` which defines `\@captype` and does `\capstart` afterwards:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypcap}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\capstartof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\capstart}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

stuff stuff \autoref{table:nmr_nitro} blah blah.

\begin{figure}

\capstartof{table}% start of table
\begin{threeparttable}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\caption{NMR of 3-nitrobenzonitrile}
\label{table:nmr_nitro}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
\textbf{Some Data} & \textbf{Assignment} \\
\midrule
8.542; 2.0 (2H); m;        & A, B \\
7.960; 2.1 (2H); m;        & C, D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Hurray, now everything is fine!

Note: Since `\capstartof` defines `\@captype` to `table`, we don't need `\captionof` anymore but could use the regular `\caption` instead.

Now back to my `caption` package: It has the `hypcap` feature implemented, and it is turned on by default. It could be turned off by using the package option `hypcap=false`, and in this case it would fix your problem. But because of the "wrong jump target" problem described above this is usually not what one wants. The `hypcap` feature is a good one since it results in good hyperlink targets.

So instead we need something like `\capstartof` here, a command which registers the correct type (by defining `\@captype`), generates a proper hyper anchor etc. Luckily, such command is already offered by the `caption` package and it's called `\captionsetup{type=...}` or `\setcaptiontype{...}` (which is usually the same). It's used internally every time a floating environment starts, but when dealing with use cases like yours it needs to be placed manually, just like in the `\capstartof` example document above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

stuff stuff \autoref{table:nmr_nitro} blah blah.

\begin{figure}% does \captionsetup{type=figure} internally
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{3-nitrobenzonitrile.png}
\caption{3-Nitrobenzonitrile with hydrogens assignments}
\label{figure:nmr_fig_nitro}

\captionsetup{type=table}% create new hyper anchor at start of table contents
\begin{threeparttable}
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\caption{NMR of 3-nitrobenzonitrile}
\label{table:nmr_nitro}
\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
\textbf{Some Data} & \textbf{Assignment} \\
\midrule
8.542; 2.0 (2H); m;        & A, B \\
7.960; 2.1 (2H); m;        & C, D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So in summary:

`\captionsetup{type=table}` is not a hack, it is a proper solution. This way not only the name typeset by `\autoref` will be fixed, but clicking on it will jump to the start of the table content, and not to the start of the figure content (or to the caption of the table).

In general `\captionof` should be avoided when the `hyperref` package is used. See also: Section "6.5 hyperref" of the `caption` package documentation.

P.S.: I'm sorry for the very late answer to this issue. Since I don't take a look at all new questions on SX regularly, and since there is no tag specific to my `caption` package, I usually miss most of the questions related to my packages, or I discover them by accident later on, like this one. So please don't hesitate to send me a link to a SX issue via e-mail, or open an issue on the Gitlab project page: https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is because you put the table in a `figure` environment. Since you are already using the `caption` package, you may e.g. do

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\begin{document}

stuff stuff \autoref{table:nmr_nitro} blah blah.

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{3-Nitrobenzonitrile with hydrogens assignments}
\label{figure:nmr_fig_nitro}


\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\captionof{table}{NMR of 3-nitrobenzonitrile}
\label{table:nmr_nitro}
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
\toprule
\textbf{Some Data} & \textbf{Assignment} \\
\midrule
8.542; 2.0 (2H); m;        & A, B \\
7.960; 2.1 (2H); m;        & C, D \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work because I need the image and the table to be guaranteed to be on the same page.

Comment: @FailureGod You can certainly make them appear on one side. The question is if you want them to float or be fixed at a given page.

Comment: @FailureGod The you could for instance wrap them in a `minipage` or in a `tabular`, depending on your layout preferences.

Comment: I need them to appear at a specific place in text. Like

 '''
 Some text
 <image and figure>
 more text
 '''

where the image and the figure are not broken by a pagebreak.

Comment: @FailureGod I added something of that sort.

Comment: Alright I tried that and its still saying "Figure".

Comment: This solution generates two warnings by the `caption` package and leads to bad hyperlink targets (clicking on the link jumps to the caption instead of content), so it's unclear to me why this answer was up-voted four times.